# Twitter Posts - from client or server?

Tags: ios, mobile, twitter, software-design

I'm creating an iPhone app that will allow users to log in with Twitter and for the app to then be able to post on their behalf.

Is it better to make post requests to Twitter from the app or from the server? Why?

Answer (score 0):

For my app I found it easier to do it on the client. If you are looking for a iOS twitter library I have it here https://github.com/narup/PSTwitterEngine Though, you can still post using iOS native twitter support. You will need this library if you are using browser based authentication

Also, didn't want to write extra code on server since i am writing server myself :)